# Distinct on column and find sum for past few months in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, distinct

I have a table like this sample:

```
     purchase_datetime    customer_id  value    purchase_id
    2013-01-08 17:13:29      45236       92        2526
    2013-01-03 15:42:35      45236       16        2565
    2013-01-03 15:42:35      45236       16        2565
    2013-03-08 09:04:52      45236       636       2563
    2013-12-08 12:12:24      45236       23        2505
    2013-12-08 12:12:24      45236       23        2505
    2013-12-08 12:12:24      45236       23        2505
    2013-12-08 12:12:24      45236       23        2505
    2013-07-08 22:35:53      35536       73        2576
    2013-07-08 09:52:03      35536        4        5526
    2013-10-08 16:23:29      52626       20        2226
...
    2013-04-08 17:49:31      52626       27        4526
    2013-12-09 20:40:53      52626       27        4626
```

Now I need find total spent sum (value) by the customer for every purchase made by that customer (purchase_id) in past few months. But  I have a problem because there are doubled purchase_id, so I need to do Distinct on purchase_id.

This is what I got so far without distinct, I don't how to approach to distinct.

```
Select customer_id
  sum(case when ( date '2017-01-01'  - purchase_datetime::DATE <=30) then value else 0 end)  as 1month,
  sum( case when ( date '2017-01-01' - purchase_datetime::DATE <=90) then value else 0 end)  as 3month,
  sum( case when ( date '2017-01-01' - purchase_datetime::DATE <=180) then value else 0 end)  as 6month,
  sum( case when ( date '2017-01-01' - purchase_datetime::DATE <=360) then value else 0 end)  as 12month

FROM table_data
GROUP BY (customer_id)
ORDER BY amount_1month DESC;
```

Maybe is better with window func?

Desired output:

```
    purchase_datetime    customer_id  value    purchase_id
    2013-01-08 17:13:29      45236       92        2526
    2013-01-03 15:42:35      45236       16        2565
    2013-03-08 09:04:52      45236       636       2563
    2013-12-08 12:12:24      45236       23        2505
    2013-07-08 22:35:53      35536       73        2576
    2013-07-08 09:52:03      35536        4        5526
    2013-10-08 16:23:29      52626       20        2226
...
    2013-04-08 17:49:31      52626       27        4526
    2013-12-09 20:40:53      52626       27        4626
```

Comment: I can't understand why you want DISTINCT here? Your GROUP BY will not return any duplicate rows.

Comment: @jarlh
What if I drop group by? I'm not sure, but when I did this, I got a huge number because of multiple rows with same data just like fifth to ninth row.

Comment: With the GROUP BY, you'll get one row per customer_id. Isn't that what you want?

Comment: @jarlh
I want one row by purchase_id, for example, I have from fifth to eighth row 4 rows with same data, I need 3 rows to disappear, drop off from data.

Comment: To make things clearer, add the expected result as well to your question. (Formatted text here too.)

Comment: @jarlh
I have edited my question. 
If there are multiple columns with the same purchase_id, I need it to be deleted, left just one...and then find sum of value for every purchase_id made by each customer. That's all, I'm sorry for being a little confusing.

Comment: Your desired output shows no sums. It is merely `select distinct * from table_data`. Is this all you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select on a subquery, and use a DISTINCT (or a GROUP BY) in that subquery.

For example:

```
SELECT 
  customer_id, 
  sum(case when purchase_datetime::DATE between current_date - interval '1 month' and current_date then "value" else 0 end)  as "1month",
  sum(case when purchase_datetime::DATE between current_date - interval '3 month' and current_date then "value" else 0 end)  as "3month",
  sum(case when purchase_datetime::DATE between current_date - interval '6 month' and current_date then "value" else 0 end)  as "6month",
  sum(case when purchase_datetime::DATE between current_date - interval '1 year' and current_date then "value" else 0 end)  as "12month"
FROM (
  select 
  distinct purchase_id, customer_id, purchase_datetime,  "value"

  -- distinct on (purchase_id) customer_id, purchase_datetime, "value" 
  -- Note: with this type of distinct you assume that for each purchase_id there is only 1 combination of the 3 other field values.

  from table_data
) p
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY "1month" DESC;
```

---

Testdata:

```
create table table_data (purchase_datetime timestamp(0),customer_id int,"value" int,purchase_id int);
insert into table_data (purchase_datetime,customer_id,"value",purchase_id) values
(current_timestamp - interval '11 month',45236,92,2526),
(current_timestamp - interval '11 month',45236,16,2565),
(current_timestamp - interval '1 month',45236,16,2565),
(current_timestamp - interval '2 month',45236,636,2563),
(current_timestamp - interval '5 month',45236,23,2505),
(current_timestamp - interval '5 month',45236,23,2505),
(current_timestamp - interval '5 month',45236,23,2505),
(current_timestamp - interval '3 month',35536,73,2576),
(current_timestamp - interval '2 month',35536,4,5526),
(current_timestamp - interval '1 month',52626,20,2226),
(current_timestamp - interval '6 month',52626,27,4526),
(current_timestamp - interval '6 month',52626,27,4626);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select customer_id, sum(value)
from (
    select distinct on (purchase_id) *
    from t
) s
where purchase_datetime >= '2017-07-01'
group by 1
;
 customer_id | sum 
-------------+-----
       35536 |  77
       52626 |  20
       45236 |  23
```